# Copy Folder Structure from one bucket to antother without copying actual data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, directory, copy

We have a requirement to create a bucket with the same directory structure as another s3 bucket, as AWS s3 is object-based storage I could not able to find any directory listing or copying command.

any solution or workaround will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below piece of code (python) will create the empty folders structure the same as other s3 bucket folder structure.

```
src_bucketName = 'source_bucket'
dest_bucketName = 'dest_bucket'
uniqPath = []

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3c = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(src_bucketName)

for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.all():
    path = my_bucket_object.key.rsplit('/',1)
    uniqPath.append(path[0])
    dir = set(uniqPath)
    udir = list(dir)

for i in udir:
    s3c.put_object(
        Bucket=dest_bucketName,
        Key=(i+'/')
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use an S3 replication rule on the bucket to copy the source to a destination bucket.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, S3 does not have "folders" in the same way that a filesystem does. However, the AWS console simulates them with zero-length objects ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html)):

> The Amazon S3 console implements folder object creation by creating a zero-byte object with the folder prefix and delimiter value as the key

So if you want to replicate the "folder" structure, you will need to do the following:

1. Iterate all objects in the bucket.
2. For each object, strip off everything *after* the last slash (`/`). For example, if you have the object `/foo/bar/baz`, you want to end up with the key `/foo/bar/` (the trailing slash is important).
3. Call `PutObject` in your language of choice, using that key and a zero-length body.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3, removing subsequent trailing components (so `/foo/bar/baz` becomes `/foo/bar/`, and that becomes `/foo/`).

You should use whatever "set" implementation your language of choice supports, to avoid attempting to create the same "folder" multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, @parsifal, for the approach.